# Can I move the name of a VSE strip (video or sound) under the strip?

Tags: interface, video-sequence-editor

In the sequencer the file name of the strip (video or sound) is written in the middle of the strip. It's annoying on a sound strip where the name hides the waveform. Can I use the Python API to write this name under the strip inside the same channel?

Can I suppress the path of the file (I can find it if needed in the properties of the strip)?

---

I tried 2.78 but there is no difference with 2.77. Is there a setting I don't know?

What I want: writing under the strips
[image: Sequencer editor wanted, writing under the strips]

What I have with 2.78
[image: Wniting over the strips]

Comment: Update to 2.78, it is enhanced now.